# How to conn.close() before Heroku Push/Redeploy for Postgresql?

Tags: python, heroku, psycopg2, heroku-postgres

As you know for `psycopg2`, you need to run:

```
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

To kill the connection to the Postgresql server so that it doesn't take up the available connections.

What I have done if the program crashes on Python is, do these two on an `exit handler`.

However, when you `commit` and `push` to Heroku, it redeploys and `conn.close()` for example isn't called. How do I automate this?

Comment: Why does it matter? Heroku should let active requests complete before the new version is live. Are you actually seeing open connections leaking?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I saw almost about 10 of my 20 connections open, I reckon they're all from commits and running of the Python script where conn.close() is never called when a new one is replacing it.

Comment: What makes you think this is related to deploying new versions? Are you entirely sure that you close connections properly in your application code? I believe Postgres will periodically reclaim stale connections, so unless you're deploying 10 to 20 times per day, I really don't think this is a deployment issue.

Comment: @Chris I do many deployments like that actually, I only see the errors once it's deployed as I'm doing it that way, so I deploy with my error fixing. I do many a day. Is that wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with deploying frequently, but you still haven't convinced me that that is the cause of this issue.